# WinRAR - Using rar.exe command line to extract all files in all archives in a folder then delete all the archives?

Tags: command-line, c#, rar, winrar, command-line-arguments

I want to use `rar.exe` via command line to extract all files in all archives in a folder then delete all the archives automatically if they extracted successfully? I tried `-df` and `-dr` to no avail. Seems like those may only for deleting the files if you're adding them to an archive.

Right now I'm using (c#):

```
string.Format("e -p{0} \"{1}\" *.* \"{2}\"", pass, fi[n].FullName, fi[n].DirectoryName)
```

Comment: Rather than what you're doing in C#, please always show the actual commands that are called.

Answer (score 0):

> Seems like those may only for deleting the files if you're adding them to an archive.

Seems to be the case, yes,

```
$ unrar --help | grep -i unrar
UNRAR 5.00 beta 8 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2013 Alexander Roshal
Usage:     unrar command -switch1 -switchN archive files...
$ unrar --help | grep del
$ unrar --help | grep unlink
$ unrar --help | grep rem
```

... no mention of removing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do something like

> - Use Process class to execute rar.exe
> - Process.WaitForExit
> - Validate whether the files have been extracted
>
>   (You could just estimate size, if you want to do it quick and dirty...)
> - If validation passes, delete the archive